# Admin & User notifications in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, notifications

I have create a help ticket section in my RoR app and I would like to notify user when Admins answer their ticket (kind of post) with comments. And on the admin side notifiy admins when a ticket is created and when user ticket a new comment on their ticket.

I am having difficulty displaying the notifications depending on the current_user. I want the current_user only to see notifications from the admin on the current_users created ticket and I want the admin to see notifications from the user when the user creates and comments a ticket.

I created a table :

Notification table :

```
Ticket.reference.
Comment.reference
User.reference
Read.boolean
```

In my Comment.rb

```
def create_notification
  @ticket = self.ticket
  @user = @ticket.created_by
  @user.notifications.create(
    ticket_id: self.ticket_id,
    comment_id: self
  )
end
```

notification.rb

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket
  belongs_to :comment
  belongs_to :user

  scope :is_read, -> {
    where(read: true)
  }

  scope :unread, -> {
   where(read: false)
  }
  attr_accessible :read,
                  :ticket_id,
                  :comment_id
end
```

notifications controllor :

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :find_user, :is_it_me?

  def display_name
    "Notifications"
  end

  def display_desc
    ""
  end

  def index
    @notifications = @user.notifications
    @notifications.each do |notification|
      notification.update_attribute(:read, true)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @notification = Notification.find(params[:id])
    @notification.destroy
    @notifications = @user.notifications
    redirect_to user_notifications_path(@user)
  end

  def find_user
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) unless params[:user_id].nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Utilisateur introuvable"
      redirect_to dashboard_path if @user.nil?
  end

   def is_it_me?
     redirect_to dashboard_path unless @user = current_user
   end
end
```

views

```
= link_to user_notifications_path(current_user), :class => "dropdown-toggle" do
        i.icon-envelope style ="font-size: 26px;" alt = "ticket"
        span.badge
          = "#{current_user.notifications.unread.count}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [public_activity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity)
Helped me to get such things up and running.

Comment: Yes I did , but I thought that I would learn more if I created it without a gem (I'm a rails newbie ^^).